# Maven and Jsig CAS 4.0RC

Tags: maven, war, pom.xml, cas, jasig

I have downloaded the code from the [repository](https://github.com/Jasig/cas)  but I have little experience to use maven (command line) to get the .war file to be included in my tomcat.

I do not have experience in this.

I have not changed the pom.xml file

I directly run the command mvn clean package but I have several errors.
Spete help me?

My goal is to generate the. War file CAS 4.0RC

I'm using the pom.xml file that I found on git (a very long file) can fit that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've downloaded the source of CAS and its by itself should be a mavenized project then, pom.xml should be inside. 
so you should just 'cd' to the root folder of your source and type

```
mvn install
```

or

```
mvn package
```

The first command will install your jar into local maven repository, the second one will only prepare the war in the target folder of the module with packaging war in the source.

If you encounter any errors, please post them here.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

It should build without any problem when executing `mvn clean install` in the CLI... What are your errors ?